# Ajax PHP Not Providing Me With Any Response Text

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Hi I am trying to work on a script to get back XML text from a php site.  However, it is not returning any data. Here is what I am doing.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getImei()
{
var imei = document.getElementById("imeiInput").value;
if (imei=="")
  {
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }


  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  } 


xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.phonesite.com/xml/api/phone.php?IMEI=" + imei,true);
xmlhttp.send();


}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="textbox" id="imeiInput"/>
    <input type="button" onClick="getImei()" id="btnSubmit" text="Submit"/>
    <p id="txtResult"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I do it this way xmlhttp.readystate stops at 1. When I put the "xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()" below the xmlhttp.send(), it says the ready state is 4 in FireBug but it completely jumps over the function without going inside of it and finishes.

Also, I did try to enter in the url with the query string directly into my browser and it returned text.  Looked at the GET request and they are the same when the Javascript sends it out and when I enter it in.

```
Date    Fri, 14 Oct 2011 01:34:05 GMT
Server  Apache
Content-Encoding    gzip
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Content-Length  87
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=100
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/xml
Request Headersview source
Host    www.phonesite.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection  keep-alive
```

I get this error in firebug for the xml text.

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{baefeeae-cd08-9641-a08f-6b3c3396e8a7} Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

Comment: People still write their own XMLHttpRequest code? Is `phonesite.com` a different domain than where the AJAX code is running?

Comment: @ceejayoz it looks like Algorhythm is and its good to see :)

Comment: David--thank you!! It did work for some reason it doesn't return any xml in firefox, but it does in safari. :-/  I am going to look around a little bit and because I think I saw a post on firefox causing problems with AJAX.  Anyways, question solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you request the responce back from the server to be XML not just text you read that response using responseXML

```
instead of "responseText"; you need for xml "responseXML"
```

this will at least return back the text and get you on your way

```
 function getImei()
 {

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

 var imei = document.getElementById("imeiInput").value;
 if (imei=="")
   {
   return;
   }

 if(xmlhttp) {
 xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.phonesite.com/xml/api/phone.php?IMEI=?" + imei, true); 

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
 document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; // if the returned           content type is is "text/xml" innerhtml will strip out the tags

 }
 }
 xmlhttp.send(null);
 }
 }
```